# How to prevent escape characters in MySQL varchar inserted by PHP PDO via jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, pdo, escaping

I think it's strange that I can't find anything on this, but that's the case.

On my site, I allow users to enter text to be stored in my database.  I use PDO to keep it safe, but then all of the dangerous characters have "\"s in front of them.

Is there an easy way to get rid of all that?  Should I be using a different datatype in MySQL?

Thanks in advance!

**No double escaping.  Laziness prevented it**

I read that just doing straight PDO made it so you didn't have to worry about escaping, sanitizing, bleaching, scrubbing, etc...

I do the standard PDO INSERT like so [How do I insert into PDO (sqllite3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176122/pdo-insert-help)

The data is transmitted by jQuery ajax.  Is that the source of the problem?  If so, how do I reverse it?

Thanks for your help!

**Specifics on problem**

I have "\"s in front of quotes and double quotes only.  Thanks!

**Versions**

PHP 5.3 for Zend Guard compatibility.  MySQL 5.5.  Apache 2.2.2.  jQuery 1.8.3

**+1 for reversal**

I'll give as many +1s as answers on how to reverse these /'s.  Thanks!

**Magic Quotes**

was the answer.  Anyone want to lengthen their answer for check?

Still looking for a SQL statement to reverse previous escaping.  Thanks!

Comment: how do danagerous character looked like? :D

Comment: big bad "'"s and """s.  They're so sharp.  They cut my database to shreds.  LOL  Thanks for looking!

Comment: Are the extra characters `/` or  \

Comment: Is it possible you're using an older version of PHP with [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php) enabled?

Comment: Yeah, PHP ~5.3 for Zend Guard compatibility.  If you think that's the problem, can you give details on how to shut off, so I can give you the check?  Thanks!

Comment: You should have a look at how your data's coming in. It is probably escaped before it hits PDO.

Comment: I swear I'm doing nothing but taking data from HTML input type text and textboxes, transmitting by POST via jQuery AJAX, and inserting into MySQL with PHP PDO.

Comment: `phpinfo()` should tell you whether it's enabled. I think the only way to control `magic_quotes_gpc` (the most likely culprit) is in your php.ini.

Comment: Can you guys tell me how to turn it off?  I have security up the ying yang, and someone else does the server stuff.  Thanks!

Comment: If you've verified with `phpinfo` that magic quotes is the problem, you can give this link to whoever has access to the php.ini file on your server: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php Note that if other code on that box relies on magic quotes to escape user input, it may cause errors or security holes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be caused by having `magic quotes` enabled on the server. In particular, it's probably the `magic_quotes_gpc` directive, which can be set in `php.ini`, `.htaccess`, etc, but not at runtime with `ini_set`.

First, double-check the output of `phpinfo()` to be sure this is the problem. If you find that magic quotes is enabled, you'll need somebody with access to the server to disable it in your `php.ini` or `.htaccess` file. The php manual explains the process here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Do be careful with this, though: If there is code running on the server that relies on magic quotes, disabling it could leave those sites vulnerable to attacks like sql injection.

Comment: For those who cannot edit php.ini, try adding to .htaccess: php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

Answer (score 0):

You've obviously got some other escaping going on in your application before it hits the PDO layer. Look for `addslashes` or `escape_string` type method calls to see if you've got that going on.

What you're seeing is a sign of double escaping.